# How do you re-attach a subversion local copy to a different remote?

Tags: svn

Our subversion repository has been moved to a new host, and we have old applications that connect to that host.  We CANNOT add an alias for the new server with the old name, how can we re-connect our checked out clients to the new repository?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Example:

```
svn switch --relocate \
    http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/path/within/repository \
    http://svnnew.example.com/new/repository/path/within/repository
```

One thing which is to remember, lets assume you checked out the project "path/within/repository" then you have to go to the **root of your working copy**, and execute the above command. it is **NOT** enough just to use the repository root (as in *svn switch --relocate http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/ http://svnnew.example.com/new/repository/*), because that wouldn't work.

Comment: This example shows that the reposity host AND path has changed. This is my case and I tried to do this but I get the message "Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL." I need to switch AND relocate as my repository host and path have both changed.

Answer (score 8):

Look up the [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html) command. In particular, the `--relocate` option is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

SVN command line - see [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)

TortoiseSVN - see [relocate dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html)