# Migrating SVN server from Linux to Windows - client implications?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, migration, ankhsvn

My IT guy just told me he wants to move our SVN server from a Linux machine to a Windows box.

We use both TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN on the client side.

Am I correct in thinking that we can just use the "Switch" command on our working folders to point to the new server?

Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think linux/windows will make any difference.   We recently migrated from one windows box to another, and used the "Relocate" command on each of our working folders, to point to the new repository. Worked fine.
See this discussion:
[How do you re-attach a subversion local copy to a different remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112770/how-do-you-re-attach-a-subversion-local-copy-to-a-different-remote/113820#113820)

And suggest to your IT guy that he should look at VisualSVNServer, which makes managing SVN on Windows really easy.  http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

And make sure that your Tortoise clients are up to date.

Comment: Note: do *not* use "switch"! Only use "relocate" in these situations.